# how to solve the error in variable references non-exit?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I get this error:

> Variable references non-existent resource : 
>   ${workspace_loc:/plugins/portlets/view-portlet/build.xml}

while running build-services in the ant view i am working with liferay6.0 on eclipse IDE .

Comment: can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: Without any context i.e. what you were doing, what you want to do, when this error came etc, it is very difficult to help with just an error. Well these type of questions are definitely good for a quiz show :-)

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it.

go to bundle folder of the workspace go to tomcat folder  inside the temp folder-> delete all files, webapps-> delete all folders, 
work->catelena ->delete local host folder.
Next go to ant view -> select clean in portal, next run compile under portal and next deploy
before deleting take backup.